# ¿Cómo especificar con XPath que tome en cuenta todos los nodos o elementos del documento?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xpath

Estoy firmando un documento XML y nesecito especificar en el XPath que están firmado el documento completo.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:clientes>
    < xs:cliente>
        <xs:nombre>
            Juan Martinez
        </xs:nombre>
        <xs:fecha_inicio>
            2016-10-2
        </xs:fecha_inicio>
    </xs:cliente>
    <xs:cliente>
        <xs:nombre>
            Jose Gonzalez
        </xs:nombre>
        <xs:fecha_inicio>
            2014-8-2
        </xs:fecha_inicio>
    </xs:cliente>
</xs:clientes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión `(//. | //@* | //namespace::*)` sirve para retornar todo los elementos del `xml`, adicionalmente [este link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/04/07/using-xpath-to-sign-specific-xml/) podria serte útil